# Codeigniter Disable Cache

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

I'm trying to learn Codeigniter and understand the basics so far, but as I try to test, it seems the cache is getting in the way. Normally when I test on localhost I make a change and instantly can see it in browser, but with Codeigniter it seems I have to wait ~1 minute for changes to be seen in browser. Is there a way to universally disable the Codeigniter cache so when developing changes happen immediately?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just put this code in the __construct function of controller

```
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
$this->output->set_header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Comment: There's something broken on the fifth line of your example code, `$this->output->set_header`

Comment: Is this supposed to appear in the generated HTML file?
Because I tried putting this in the view controller's constructor and those new headers did not appear in the generated HTML file :-/ Did I miss a step here?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all the cached items in the application/cache folder:

```
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html
```

Answer (score 0):

*IF* you enabled the cache, you need to disable it (comment out the cache).
Otherwise it may be your browser caching, you could force a SHIFT-F5 (in most browsers).

The cache will only work if you have it so defined in your controller etc; not randomly.

Comment: AFAIK, i have used Ctrl+F5 or Command+R for overriding the browser cache while refreshing, Shift+f5 looks strange..simply it doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class MY_Cacheoff extends CI_Cacheoff {
        /**
         * author: https://www.blazingcoders.com
         */
        function disable_cache() {
            $this->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
            $this->set_header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
            $this->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
            $this->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
            $this->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
        }

    }
```

For Detail Explanation check the link

https://www.blazingcoders.com/how-to-disable-browser-cache-easily-for-particular-individual-and-separate-function-and-controller-in-codeigniter