# Why I cannot Upload file on Dropzone in codeigniter when CSRF is TRUE

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf-protection, dropzone

Why I cannot Upload file on Dropzone in codeigniter when csrf_protection is TRUE? and when I make "csrf_protection" is FALSE the upload has works, but can I make "csrf_protection" is TRUE and works fine ?

this is my controllers :

```html
function proses_upload(){
        $config['upload_path']   = FCPATH.'/upload-foto/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico';
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
        $token=$this->input->post('token_foto');
        $nama=$this->upload->data('file_name');
        $this->db->insert('foto',array('nama_foto'=>$nama,'token'=>$token));
        }
 }

function remove_foto(){
 $token=$this->input->post('token');
 $foto=$this->db->get_where('foto',array('token'=>$token));

 if($foto->num_rows()>0){
 $hasil=$foto->row();
 $nama_foto=$hasil->nama_foto;
 if(file_exists($file=FCPATH.'/upload-foto/'.$nama_foto)){
  unlink($file);
  }
 $this->db->delete('foto',array('token'=>$token));
  }
 echo "{}";

}
```

this is in views :

```html
  
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var foto_upload= new Dropzone(".dropzone",{
url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/upload/proses_upload') ?>",
maxFilesize: 2,
method:"post",
acceptedFiles:"image/*",
paramName:"userfile",
dictInvalidFileType:"Type file ini tidak dizinkan",
addRemoveLinks:true,
});

foto_upload.on("sending",function(a,b,c){
 a.token=Math.random();
 c.append("token_foto",a.token);
});

foto_upload.on("removedfile",function(a){
 var token=a.token;
 $.ajax({
  type:"post",
  data:{token:token},
  url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/upload/remove_foto') ?>",
  cache:false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(){
   console.log("Foto terhapus");
  },
  error: function(){
   console.log("Error");
  }
 });
});
```

and this is in my config.php specially on CSRF :

```html
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

Comment: Is your form being cached? See: [link]https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/http_cache/form_csrf_caching.html

Comment: @Jamie_D I think yes, but I dont know much about it

Comment: You should use the information from the above link, or set your form's page to "no cache" More info here: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775382/codeigniter-disable-cache

Comment: so I just disable cache if I wanted to set TRUE on csrf_protection ? I just recently following your link to disable cache but it doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you clear your browser cache as well and do a hard refresh (Ctrl-F5)

Comment: You should also to manually delete cached items in the application/cache folder

Comment: @Jamie_D still doesn't work

Comment: While I still think caching is your issue here, I would use a developer console to check for any other unforeseen problems (i.e. cross site blocking, CORS errors etc.). You may try one of the techniques illustrated  here [link]https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/http_cache/esi.html or here [link]https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/templating/hinclude.html